# For loops in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, for-loop

I have many elements stored in four lists and I need sum for everything with each other in database.

I write this in Python:

```
result = []
for vert1 in vertical_result[vertical_tmp[0]]:
    for vert2 in vertical_result[vertical_tmp[1]]:
        for hor1 in horizontal_result[horizontal_tmp[0]]:
            for hor2 in horizontal_result[horizontal_tmp[1]]:
                gridSQL = "SELECT SUM(order_price_czk) FROM p_partner_all WHERE {}='{}' AND {}='{}' AND {}='{}' AND {}='{}'".format(vertical_tmp[0], vert1, vertical_tmp[1], vert2, horizontal_tmp[0], hor1, horizontal_tmp[1], hor2)
                cur = self._getCursor()
                cur.execute(gridSQL)
                result.append(cur.fetchall())
```

It is unefficient call sql every loop, so I need write it in MySQL syntax.

Here is some example what variables includes:

```
vertical_tmp = [source, city]
horizontal_tmp = [currency, street]         
vertical_result = {source: [CZ, PL, GB...], city: [Prague, Berlin...]}          
horizontal_result {currency: [CZK, EUR...], street: [street1, street2...]}
```

Keys and values in dictionaries above are stored in database and I have already them.

I need list where is saved each field of grid SUM(order_price_czk).

Thanks for help

Comment: can you explain a little more what you want to do? give a sample from the table also

Comment: Please provide samples of what all those variables contain. Is there a reason why you have to use dynamic column names? And finally, string formatting values in to SQL queries is error prone and unsafe. Use your driver's placeholders. Since you produce a product of vert res 1 & 2 and horizontal 1 & 2, I think a single query with four IN clauses would do.

Comment: Thanks. I have added some informations.